# Get all comments children WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Helo, i want to show all comments but without parent comments.
Maybe like this:

```
> - Parent
> --- Child 1,
> --- Child 2,
> ----- Child 3
> ----- Child 4
> -------- Child 5
```

> I want only get: Child 1, Child 2, .... Child N

Try with code below, but show parents comments only without Childs.,

```
$comments = get_comments( array(
    'status'    => 'approve',
    'user_id'   => $author->ID,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'parent'    => 0
) );
```

If use this code., show all comments include childs and parents.

```
$comments = get_comments( array(
    'status'    => 'approve',
    'user_id'   => $author->ID,
    'post_type' => 'post',
) );
```

Please help, thank you.

Comment: $comment__not_in or $post__not_in maybe (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments)

Comment: @Paul , if have a thousand comments., thats way not good.

Comment: So when you say Child do mean replies to comments or comments of child pages? I'm thinking you are getting all of the comments on your site but only want comments from child pages and not top level pages?